# Galilean transformations

Tags: physics, lie-groups

How do you prove that every galilean transformation of the space $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^3$ can be written in a unique way as the composition of a rotation, a translation and uniform motion? Thanks!

Comment: Please explain "uniform motion" and clarify whether you are in 4 dimensions or 3 dimensions or 6 dimensions.

Comment: @MarkB: Since the question as written refers to galilean  transformations of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^3$, doesn't it at least imply very strongly that it is considering one time dimension and three spatial?

Comment: @MJD - Thanks for clarification ...

Comment: @Mark Bennet: By uniform motion, I mean something of the form g(t,x) = (t,x+v*t), where v is a three-component velocity and x is a vector in R3.

Comment: @user34801 If you don't get a good answer here after a couple of days, you might try asking on http://physics.stackexchange.com/ , where people are more likely to have a clue about galilean transformations.

Comment: The basic plan would be to use the translation and uniform motion to fix an origin in space and time - then you are left with a rigid motion of space with a fixed point, which would be a rotation.

Comment: This is a problem from page 6 of V.I Arnold's "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this problem appears in V.I Arnold's "*Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*".

A simple proof can be found on page 7 of [this](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/teaching/math439/pdf/chapter1.pdf) nice lecture series on the topic. In essence, you use the affine property of the transformation to show that the time cannot be dilated, the space component must be multiplied by a orthogonal matrix plus a constant vector. The uniqueness follows by considering to different parameterizations and proving equality.